# Template routes not respecting URL

Tags: routes

Say i have a url: `/lists/more-lists/even-more-lists` and i have a route  `lists/more-lists/*`.

If i hit `example.com/lists/more-lists/even-more-lists` then it tries to load the index template (not the template defined by my route)

If i hit  `example.com/lists/more-lists/foo` then it loads the template defined by my template route.

I should add, that the url segments are category url's.

Comment: Looks like you got this sorted over on the Craft Slack group. Would you mind adding an answer here?

Answer (score 3):

So, if a category section has "has it's own url's" ticked, then the template defined there will take precedence over the custom route. Custom routes i'm told are a fallback and will not override already set routing.